# Eslint - Restrict imports from root and enforce tree-shaking

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, eslint

I'd like to block imports directly from the root of a dependency (@material-ui/icons) in my application, as well as enforce tree-shaking.

> Valid - `import AccessAlarmIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm";`

> Invalid - `import AccessAlarmIcon from "@material-ui/icons/";`

Material-ui has a good guide on setting up tree-shaking, but it does not enforce the no-root rule above.

```js
rules: {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": ["@material-ui/*/*/*", "!@material-ui/core/test-utils/*"],
        "message": "Tree-shaking is enforced for @material-ui, import dependencies "
      }
    ]
}
```

Will just adding "@material-ui/*" as a pattern solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

The following no-restricted-imports rule blocks imports from `@material-ui/icons` as described in the Material UI Guide.

```
rules: {
"no-restricted-imports": [
  "error",
  {
    "paths": ["@material-ui/icons"],
    "patterns": ["@material-ui/*/*/*", "!@material-ui/core/test-utils/*"],
  }
]
```

}

`"patterns": ["@material-ui/icons", "!@material-ui/icons/*"]` did not have the desired effect and imports from `@material-ui/icons/*` were also blocked. Here is a description of the cause [Eslint no-restricted-imports only restrict importing from a package root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330715/eslint-no-restricted-imports-only-restrict-importing-from-a-package-root)