# Eslint no-restricted-imports only restrict importing from a package root?

Tags: javascript, eslint

E.g. I want to restrict importing `react-use`, but allow `react-use/lib/usePrevious`. I tried:

```
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-imports': [2, { patterns: [
      'react-use',
    ] }],
  },
```

And

```
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-imports': [2, { patterns: [
      'react-use',
      '!react-use/*',
    ] }],
  },
```

However, in both case, I get an error for:

```
import usePrevious from 'react-use/lib/usePrevious';
```

I only want an error for:

```
import something from 'react-use';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation with the [`ignore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore) library that ESLint uses to check each pattern. It was built to replace existing file ignore methods with something more compact and barebones.

Specifically, the problem seems to be that this ignore system assumes your file structure is strictly directory-like, where restricting `react-use` and ignoring `!react-use/*` implies that `react-use` is a folder. However, with a module import structure, `react-use` can refer to a file (via its `index.js`) and simultaneously contain subfolders like `react-use/lib` making it usable as both a file *and* a folder.

So it won't be possible to ignore the base of the module while restricting a subpath.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing with lodash.

For Treeshaking, I wanted to restrict

> import {get} from 'lodash';

but allow

> import get from 'lodash/get';

eslint config for this,

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
      'error',
      {
        paths: [
          {
            name: 'lodash',
            message:
              "Please use `import [package] from 'lodash/[package]'` instead."
          }
        ],
        patterns: ['!lodash/*']
      }
    ]
```

You can try the same for your package.

Comment: Not working. Did you try in the playground

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What effect does this have on treeshaking?